# Apache Airflow creating tasks dynamically in version 2.2.2

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to implement dynamic tasks in version of airflow(2.2.2) that we use. The use case is - files are received on S3 and airflow consumes them via a custom SQS operator, then we submit spark jobs on EMR based on the type of file we received .

I have successfully implemented (demo) this on a higher version of Airflow (2.4) using Dynamic Task Groups . But I am also trying to implement a work around on 2.2.2 , is it possible ?
(v2.4 code for reference)

```
with DAG('task_group_demo',start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 22),catchup=False) as dag:
def dummy_task(task_id):
    dummy_task = DummyOperator( task_id = task_id, dag = dag)
    return dummy_task

with TaskGroup(group_id="emr_task_group",dag= dag) as emr_task_group:
    def _spark_task(files):
        print(f"spark task file = {files}")

    def _sensor_task(files):
        print(f" sensor task file = {files}")

    files = [['file1'],['file2'],['file3']]

    spark_task = PythonOperator.partial(task_id="spark_task",python_callable=_spark_task,dag=dag).expand(op_args = files)
    sensor_task = PythonOperator.partial(task_id="sensor_task",python_callable = _sensor_task, dag=dag).expand(op_args = files)

    spark_task >> sensor_task

dummy_task("start")>> emr_task_group >> dummy_task("end")
```

Can we achieve the same on 2.2.2 with a for loop ?